# Unity containers calls non default ctor

Tags: c#, unity-container

I call

```
mActionLogManager = container.Resolve<IActionLogManager>();
```

and when debugging I see it runs through only the non default ctor

```
  public ActionLogManager(IUnityContainer container)
        {
            Init(container);
        }
```

Doesn't `unity` always calls the parameter-less ctor?

I have tried to write and delete the parameter-less ctor.

- It didn't go through it when it existed,
- and didn't throw an exception when was missing.

**update:**
and if so, how it knows what parameters to fill in the ctor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the default behavior of Unity. It tries to resolve an instance by using the ctor with the most parameters. If you want to instruct Unity to use the default ctor you need to register the type as follows:

```
container.Register<IActionLogManager,MyActionLogManager>(new InjectionConstructor());
```

Comment: thanks, but how it knows what parameters to fill in the ctor?

Comment: @EladBenda It looks them up into its internal registry and fills them in if there is a match. That works well for classes and interfaces but usually fails for strings, integers etc. (See [this article for explanations on newables and injectables](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/09/30/to-new-or-not-to-new/)). If no matching mapping is registered Unity will fail at runtime.

Comment: @SebastianWeber thanks, but I don't get it.  `internal registry` looks for matching param name from other method invocation? as I never called  `public ActionLogManager(IUnityContainer container)`

Comment: @Elad Benda: It looks NOT for matching param name, but for matching type to pass in as parameter to the ctors. The UnityContainer registers itself with the interface IUnityContainer in its internal registry.

Comment: @EladBenda Jehof already gave the answer. Matching parameters against Unity's internal registry is done by their type. Only if you specify a `ParameterOverride` in the call to `container.Resolve<T>` the name of the parameter is of interest.

Answer (score 2):

Given a choice of several constructors, Unity will call the one that has the *most* parameters - to give the richest set of services. If you want to override it, add the `[InjectionConstructor]` attribute to the constructor you that you want called.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660875%28v=pandp.20%29):

> When a target class contains more than one constructor, Unity will use the one that has the InjectionConstructor attribute applied. If there is more than one constructor, and none carries the InjectionConstructor attribute, Unity will use the constructor with the most parameters. If there is more than one constructor that is the "longest" with the same number of parameters, Unity will raise an exception.

Comment: I would drop the `InjectionConstructorAttribute` ([see here why](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/01/27/WhatsSoDangerousAboutADIAttribute.aspx).